# Is there a way to calculate the total running hours and minutes between times when grouping by an id using R

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I want to sum the total running hours & mins session times for each shop_id. The below dataframe is an example of the structure of the data. A shop_id can have multiple session start and end times which are in 24hr format and some of these can run concurrently.

There are a few rules required for the logic when summing the totals;

-The concurrent sessions only can be counted once e.g. two sessions at 9:00 to 12:00 the total is 3 hours

-Exceptions to this can happen when overlaps occur when one session extends past the end of another session e.g. 9:00 to 12:00 & 9:15 to 12:15 the total here is 3 hours 15 mins

```
#sample df
df <- data.frame(shop_id = c("1","1","2","2","2","3","3","3","4","5"),
                 session_start_time = c("09:00","12:00","09:00","09:15","13:00","09:00"
                                ,"09:00","13:00","08:30","09:30"), 
                 session_end_time = c("12:00","16:00","12:00","12:15","16:00","12:00"
                                ,"12:00","15:00","11:30","12:30")
                 )
```

Preferred Output

```
Shop_id Hours Mins 
1         7     0
2         6    15
3         5     0
4         3     0
5         3     0
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a problem where there are gaps within a period.  If there are none, then one solution is to take the minimum and maximum for each shop and calculate the period. i.e.

```
library(dplyr)

df_low <- df %>% 
  group_by(shop_id) %>% 
  select(shop_id, session_start_time) %>% 
  slice_min(session_start_time, with_ties = FALSE)
  
df_high <- df %>% 
  group_by(shop_id) %>% 
  select(shop_id, session_end_time) %>% 
  slice_max(session_end_time, with_ties = FALSE)

left_join(df_low, df_high, by = "shop_id") %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("session"), lubridate::hm)) %>% 
  mutate(period = session_end_time - session_start_time) %>% 
  mutate(hours = period %/% lubridate::hours(1), minutes = period %/% lubridate::minutes(1) - hours*60) %>% 
  select(shop_id, hours, minutes)

  shop_id hours minutes
  <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 1           7       0
2 2           7       0
3 3           6       0
4 4           3       0
5 5           3       0
```

However this gets shop 2 and 3 wrong, as both have gaps.

Alternatively, if there were no overlaps, then you could work out each of the periods and add them by shop.

However, where there are both gaps and overlaps, it is problematic.

Comment: So I have tried a similar solution taking max/min for each shop_id but that is exactly where I found the challenge the data has gaps and overlaps and the logic needs to account for them.